# Loader manager inside Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-loadermanager

I'm trying to create custom `Dialog` with `ListView` inside it. For loading data from DB I tried to use `LoaderManager`, but there is  no method  `getLoaderManager()` in `Dialog` class.Does anybody know how can I get it? Or how can I use `LoaderManager` inside `Dialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and extend [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead; inside `DialogFragment` custom class you should have visibility to `getLoaderManager()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A dialog is usually created and managed by an Activity, which is its owner. You could get this Activity by calling `Dialog.getOwnerActivity()`[1] and use its LoaderManager.

Be careful though, the documentation states that this method may in some cases return `null`.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getOwnerActivity()